# How to hang shelf on 2cm thin wall?

Tags: wood, concrete, walls, hanging

I would like to somehow saw out a wood board that fits into the corner as seen on the picture below. The problem is that both walls are only 2cm thin. The shelf needs to be able to hold a pair of shoes.

Are there way to hang a shelf/wood board between two walls without screws?

[image]

Comment: What are the walls made of? 2 CM thick suggests drywall, but the picture suggests brick or concrete. Both are much thicker than 2 CM and can easily support high weights using a wall plug or screw anchor.

Comment: I suppose it is some sort of very fragile concrete. The left wall is the air duct, and that's how I know it is only 2cm thin. The back wall is the back of my bathroom, and have the same thickness. To the right of the picture have I patched a hole with concrete. Would it be possible to glue the wood shelf to the walls after they have been painted?

Comment: Gluing to paint rarely work for any substantial weight, and a shelf with shoes on it will probably cause the paint to peel, even if the glue does stick to the paint itself. You can try scraping off the paint and glue directly to the wall material. Again, 2 CM of concrete is way to thin and is quite unlikely. I'd suggest verifying the exact material of the wall.